# Batch change order information as order status for specific Woocommerce order IDs

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I have a list of order IDs (~400) that are currently not in the correct order status that I need to change, I would also want to update their payment method.

What is the most efficient and best way to approach this?

So far my thought process is to have an array of Order Ids, run through them and then `$order->update_status( 'custom-status' )` on each of them. However I am not sure the best way to run this to make sure that the server won't timeout and can do them in batches etc.

Answer (score 0):

To update the order status of an array of order Ids, you can use many ways *(but always make a database backup before, or at least the `wp_posts` table)*.

**Note:** Woocommerce order `post_status` start always by **`wc-`**.

**1) The best way** is to use a lightweight, very efficient and unique SQL query with the `WPDB` WordPress Class, this way :

```
global $wpdb;

$new_status = 'wc-custom-status';
$product_ids = array(37, 53, 57, 63, 80); // The array of product Ids
$product_ids = implode(',', $product_ids);

$wpdb->query( "
    UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}posts
    SET post_status = '$replacement_user_id'
    WHERE ID IN ($product_ids)
    AND post_type = 'shop_order'
" );
```

---

**2) Another way** *(heavier)* is to update the status of an array of order Ids is to use WordPress `wp_update_post()` function in a foreach loop, this way:

```
$new_status = 'wc-custom-status';
$product_ids = array(37, 53, 57, 63, 80); // The array of product Ids
$product_ids = implode(',', $product_ids);

foreach ( $orders_ids as $order_id ) {
    wp_update_post( array('ID' => $order_id, 'post_status' => $new_status) );
}
```

Both codes are tested and works.

You can embed the code in a function and trigger it from a hook (or even using a shortcode).

**I not recommend you** to use the `WC_Product` method `update_status()`, as it will be very heavy *(and it will send a notification to the customer, for specific order statuses)*